# How can I save my ListView that it is opened again when i start my app new?

Tags: listview

Hi im really new in programming so sorry for mistakes i made, my problem is that i wanted a dynamic listview. 
I got my code so far that i can add new values to my list view. But if i close the app and restart it they are gone.

So now im searching for a possibility to save this ListView in a .txt file that i can read at every app start. I found this:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

but i can't get how i do this with my list view.

Maybe you can give me some help

bg

Fab

Answer (score 0):

if you have knowledge of SharedPreferences, you can store your list in sharedpreferences. Use Gson() to convert your list to json string and store that json string in sharedPreferences. Every time you start your app, check if there is json string in sharedpreferences, and if YES, then populate your list from that json string.

check below code

Make a separate class to manage your SharedPreferences as i have a class below.

```
public class PrefsManager {
            // final string below representing name of sharedPreferences
            private final String SHARED_PREFERENCES="com.example.myApp.sharedPreferences";

            private final String TASKS_LIST="tasks_list";
            private final String IS_TASKS_LIST_AVAILABLE="is_tasksList_available";

            private static PrefsManager prefsManager=null; //reference to PrefsManager object

            private Context context;
            private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
            private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

            // constructor is private in order 
            //to make this class a Singleton 

            private PrefsManager(Context context){

           this.context=context;
 sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES,context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            }

            //public method used to make an object of PrefsManager class, 
           //and return reference of it.

            public static synchronized PrefsManager getPrefsManager(Context context){
                if(prefsManager==null){
                    prefsManager=new PrefsManager(context);
                }
                return prefsManager;
            }

        //public method which receive list of Task, 
        //convert it to Json String, and stores in sharedpreferences

        public void saveTasksList(List<Task> tasksList){
                if(tasksList.size()>0){
                    editor.putBoolean(IS_TASKS_LIST_AVAILABLE,true);
                    editor.putString(TASKS_LIST,new Gson().toJson(tasksList)); // if size > 0, save the list
                }
                else{
                    editor.putBoolean(IS_TASKS_LIST_AVAILABLE,false);
    editor.putString(TASKS_LIST,""); // else save empty string in sharedpreferences
                }
                editor.apply();
            }

            // check if list is saved in sharedpreferences or not and return true or false
            public boolean isTasksListAvailable(){
                return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(IS_TASKS_LIST_AVAILABLE,false); 
            }

            // public method which convert stored json string into
            //  ArrayList<Task> and return this list.

            public ArrayList<Task> getTasksList(){
                return new Gson().fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString(TASKS_LIST,""),
                        new TypeToken<ArrayList<Task>>(){}.getType());
            }
        }
```

Inside my activity i declared a List of Tasks as follow.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    private TodaysTasks_Adapter adapter;
    private List<Task> tasksList;
RecyclerView rvTodaysTask;
    private PrefsManager prefsManager;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activit_addnewtask);

        rvTodaysTask.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        rvTodaysTask.setHasFixedSize(true);
        tasksList=new ArrayList<>();
        prefsManager=PrefsManager.getPrefsManager(getActivity());
        if(prefsManager.isTasksListAvailable()){
            tasksList.addAll(prefsManager.getTasksList());
        }

        adapter=new TodaysTasks_Adapter(getActivity(), tasksList);
        rvTodaysTask.setAdapter(adapter);
}

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        prefsManager.saveTasksList(tasksList);
    }

}// activity ends here
```

Remember i am using List of Tasks. Task is an object in my application. You can use List of Strings or any custom object.

Also you need to incldue Gson library in gradle dependencies as follow

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this. But first i need to read into shared Preferences. Thanks for your fast answer.

Comment: You can go through these tutorials about sharedpreferences. follow the following link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm